# Mutating the result of boost::combine

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors, c++17

I'm would expect the following code to compile and modify the value of `v1` to be `{7, 9, 11, 13, 15}` after the range-based for loop.

```
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v1{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::vector<int> v2{6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  for(auto&& [a, b] : boost::combine(v1, v2)) {
    a += b;
  }


  return 0;
}
```

But I get the following compile error (with `g++ -std=c++17`):

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('int' and 'boost::tuples::cons<int &, boost::tuples::cons<int &, boost::tuples::null_type> >::tail_type' (aka
      'boost::tuples::cons<int &, boost::tuples::null_type>'))
    a += b;
    ~ ^  ~
1 error generated.
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `b` is `tuple` (in boost it is internal `cons` helper template taking 2 parameters as *head* and *tail*) whose head refers to `int` (as second field of original tuple - returned by `combine`), you can use `boost::get` to read this:

```
  for(auto&& [a, b] : boost::combine(v1, v2)) {
    a += boost::get<0>(b);
  }
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/DnKaH_)

---

On boost tuple [reference](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/tuple/doc/html/tuple_advanced_interface.html#tuple_advanced_interface.cons_lists) site we can read

> Tuples are internally represented as cons lists. For example, the
>   tuple
>
> `tuple<A, B, C, D>` inherits from the type
>
> `cons<A, cons<B, cons<C, cons<D, null_type> > > >`

When iterating for all elements returned by `boost::combine` with `auto& q`, `q` is `tuple` and by calling `get<N>(q)` (where `N` can be 0 or 1) we are getting `int&`.

But in structured bindings version - `auto&& [a,b]`, `a` refers to `int&` and `b` refers to boost internal `cons` struct, that is why we need to use `get<0>` to access the second integer value from input sequence.

Comment: This suggests something weird (bug in boost?), because doing "standard" `for(auto &q : ...) { boost::get<0>(q) += boost::get<1>(q) }` works.

Comment: Should have read the error message properly ... I'm very satisfied with your answer (but totally not satisfied with the fact that this `boost::get<0>` is needed!)

Comment: I wonder why it is done that `b` is a tuple? For me this is unexpected. Probably this handles uneven lengths of sequences.